# How to send data from Power App to Power Automate every x seconds?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-formula

I am using a simple setup in an Power App for the app to function as an IoT data simulator.
Data is created in the Power Apps, sent to the Power Automate Flow that then sends the data onwards to an IoT Central Device Bridge (or any back-end URL for that matter).

Users can set slider values, counter vales, info/warning/error messages and one of the sliders is also using the underlying DeviceMotion API for settings its value (set by shaking the device).

I have set up a fully working Power Automate flow that the Power App app connects and sends its current data to. That setup works fine, but the sending/calling of the flow is done when I click a specific button, i.e. not every x seconds.

What I would like to to is to aggregate the "max motion value" over x seconds/minutes and send the measurements on scheduled basis and not based on the manual key press.

One could of course send data on every value change but that will not likely be effective.

Is it even possible to setup a Power App "function" to run as scheduled?
Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this without have to send data on every change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either attach the Flow to a Timer object or attach it to a Button and then have the Timer call the Button. Then you can choose the duration of the timer, whether the flow kicks off when the timer starts or stops, and if you want the timer to run repeatedly.

Personally, I use the Button/Timer option when I have Flows that need to kick off when a screen appears rather than putting it in the OnPageLoad section. Makes it easier to reuse for other use cases.